# Let $p$ be a prime number. For all $1 \le k,r < p$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $nk \equiv r \pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm solving a problem in group theory. A key argument in my attempt is to assess if the following statement is true.

> Let $p$ be a prime number. For all $1 \le k,r < p$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $nk \equiv r \pmod{p}$.

I tested for some small numbers on MS Excel for which it holds true. Could you please elaborate if it's actually true? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have learned about modular inverses, then there's a quick argument that the answer is yes: take any $n\equiv rk^{-1}\pmod p$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field, hence there is always a solution

Comment: Thank you @GregMartin! I have not learned any class on number theory :((

Comment: No worries, this is a good excuse! Just google "existence of modular inverses" or something and you'll see a proof from first principles.

Comment: @GregMartin: the existence of $k^{-1}$ relies on the very fact that the OP wants to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $p-1$ numbers $nk\bmod p$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,p-1$. These numbers are all different, because if $nk=mk\bmod p$, that means that $(n-m)k$ is a multiple of $p$, which can only happen if $n-m$ is a multiple of $p$ (because $p$ is prime). This in turn can only happen if $m=n$ (because both $m$ and $n$ are less than $p$). Note also that none of them can be zero, for a similar reason.

So the $p-1$ numbers $nk\bmod p$ are equal to the $p-1$ numbers $1,2,\ldots,p-1$ in some order. Hence one of them must be equal to $r$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Fermat's little theorem in your toolbox, then let $n=rk^{p-2}$. It'll follow that $nk=rk^{p-1}\equiv r\cdot1=r$ mod $p$.

If you don't have Fermat's little theorem handy, you can prove a weak version that says $k^m\equiv1$ mod $p$ for *some* positive integer $m$, as follows:  the powers of $k$ cannot all be distinct mod $p$, so we must have $k^r\equiv k^s$ for some integers $r$ and $s$ with $1\le r\lt s$. Writing this as $p\mid k^r(k^{s-r}-1)$, we see that $p\not\mid k$ implies $p\mid(k^{s-r}-1)$, which means $k^{s-r}\equiv1$ mod $p$. As before, let $n=rk^{m-1}$ (with $m=s-r\ge1$), and we have $nk=rk^m\equiv r\cdot1=r$ mod $p$.